# Expo set dynamic database query in sqlite database

Tags: expo

In expo I'm able to execute a database query like so:

```
      db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
          'UPDATE mytable SET eight = (?) WHERE value_id = (?)', ['off', this.state.narrative.values]
        )
      },
    (err) => console.error(err),
    () => this.setState({ isSelected: false })
  );
```

This works and it would set the table "mytable", column "eight" to 'off'.
My challenge is I'd like to do something like this:

```
let dynamicColumn = 'eight';
'UPDATE mytable SET dynamicColumn = (?) WHERE value_id = (?)'
```

I've tried the following:

```
'UPDATE mytable SET (?) = (?) WHERE value_id = (?)', [dynamicColumn, 'off', this.state.narrative.values]
```

Also some concatenation: 
    'UPDATE mytable SET' + dynamicColumn + ' = (?) WHERE value_id = (?)', ['off', this.state.narrative.values]

Updated attempt:

```
  let dynamicColumn = 'eight';
  db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
      'UPDATE dr_report_narrative SET ${dynamicColumn} = (?) WHERE value_id = (?)', ['off', this.state.narrative.values]
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use Template literals pattern and also validate if you have  right scope declaration of dynamicColumn with value:

```
let dynamicColumn = 'eight';
let sql  =  `UPDATE mytable SET ${dynamicColumn} = (?) WHERE value_id = (?)`;
```

Updated:

```
 let dynamicColumn = 'eight';
  db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
      `UPDATE dr_report_narrative SET ${dynamicColumn} = (?) WHERE value_id = (?)`, ['off', this.state.narrative.values]
    )
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Exact error is "Error code 1: unrecognized token: "$".  @Oleg

Comment: Did you put ` not ' in in syntax of SQL string it's make sense.

Comment: Are you trying this on expo also?  Or just plain js?  @Oleg.

Comment: Can you post your changes?

Comment: As said before change to tx.executeSql( `

Comment: start and end of string with ` not '

Comment: As said before? You never said that before.  What do you mean "start and end of string with ' not ' @Oleg

Comment: Syntax error on the updated answer you provided @Oleg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199856/discussion-between-oleg-and-fabriciog).

Answer (score 0):

this clear way to pass dynamic parameters in the tx function :

```
const addName = (dater, noter, serviceType) => {

    /* #debuger parameters 
console.log("log insert not Empty -->", dater, noter, serviceType)*/


    db.transaction(
        tx => {
            tx.executeSql('UPDATE Names SET dbdate=? , dbnotes=? , dbtype=?  WHERE track_id = 1 ', [dater, noter, serviceType],
                (txObj, resultSet) => console.log('db data res ------>', resultSet.dbnotes),
                (txObj, error) => console.log('Error insert', error));
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Names', [], (_, { rows }) => { rows._array.length > 1 ? console.log("rows length: ", rows._array.length) : null });
            update();


        });


}
```

[image]